# Autofac RegisterDecorator Error

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, ioc-container, autofac

I'm having some problems with the RegisterDecorator method in Autofac.

I currently have a nameless implementation of IUserManager, registered like so:

```
builder.RegisterType<UserManager>().As<IUserManager>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

I am trying to add a nameless decorator to this implementation:

```
builder.RegisterDecorator<IUserManager>(inner => new UserManager2(inner), null);
```

However, I am receiving the following error:

*The service IUserManager cannot be both the adapter's from and to parameters - these must differ.*

Why must they differ? I thought the whole point of using decorators is so that you can transparently add zero-to-many decorators. Surely the implementation and the decorator must have the same interface AND keys to achieve this?

Comment: Hi Lawrence, ordering of decorators usually turns out to be important enough that transparent schemes require augmentation with an order. Autofac just skips the transparency bit altogether (and it is a necessity of the implementation ;)) Cheers!

Comment: @Nicholas - The ordering is sometimes important, sure. But I don't see how this helps my issue. Are you saying the RegisterDecorator method was a bad idea and I shouldn't use it?

Comment: No - as Ben points out, there are numerous ways to implement decorators, and the chosen one is the most broadly applicable. The transparent decorators you're seeking can be implemented by hooking the `Activating` event and replacing `e.Instance` with the decorator as shown in http://code.google.com/p/autofac/source/browse/contrib/Source/AutofacContrib.DynamicProxy2/RegistrationExtensions.cs#82.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Autofac's `RegisterDecorator` cannot be used as you would like.  This is by design.  As [Nick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/138206/nicholas-blumhardt) says in a comment on your question.

> Ordering of decorators usually turns out to be important enough that
>   transparent schemes require augmentation with an order. Autofac just
>   skips the transparency bit altogether (and it is a necessity of the
>   implementation).

So, you have to to register the type to be decorated as a Named service using `Named` in place of your `As` and specify *either* a fromKey or toKey (of course you can specify both as well).  The correct usage of RegisterDecorator is explained in [this blog post](http://nblumhardt.com/2011/01/decorator-support-in-autofac-2-4/).

The following code will work.

```
var cb = new ContainerBuilder();
cb.RegisterType<UserManager>().Named<IUserManager>("inner").InstancePerLifetimeScope();
cb.RegisterDecorator<IUserManager>((c, inner) => new UserManager2(inner), fromKey : "inner");
cb.Build();
```

You have also expressed in the comments below that this will not work in the case you have no decorators.  I would suggest you use conditional registration in this case or a pass through decorator.

Update:  Another update based on [Nick's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/138206/nicholas-blumhardt) comment on the question.  If you do not like either of these suggestions, an alternative to `RegisterDecorator` is to use the  `Activating` event.  As Nick writes:

> The transparent decorators you're seeking can be implemented by
>   hooking the Activating event and replacing e.Instance with the
>   decorator as shown in
>   [this source code](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/source/browse/contrib/Source/AutofacContrib.DynamicProxy2/RegistrationExtensions.cs#82)

Comment: But why? What if there are no decorators? Naming the implementation differently means it wont be injected into other services in the absence of a decorator. My system shouldn't have to rely on there being at least one decorator. My system is developed on a multi-tier architecture, with the base tier providing a *working* service which *may* be decorated by higher level tiers. Sorry but -1.

Comment: Can't you just put a conditional in the registration?  If there are no  decorators, don't register as Named and don't call RegisterDecorator?

Comment: Another option would be to always register a pass through decorator (that does nothing but call the inner implementation).  This is not pretty, but it is an option.  What reason for giving my answer a -1?  You don't mention the "no decorators" in your question.  I don't think my answer meets the criteria here http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-down  Comment would have sufficed.

Comment: Apologies if the vote-down seemed harsh, but you simply pointed me to the standard (and only) documentation for the method, which I hoped you had assumed I'd read. I had specifically said I don't want a named implementation service. The two solutions you have provided would work. However, these seem like nasty hacks for something which *should* be provided out-the-box.

Comment: I don't assume anything.  If it is not in the question, it is not in the question (if anything, the fact that you were using the API incorrectly would suggest you *had not* read it) .  Conditional registration is not a nasty hack.  It is one of the core reasons you might use a container.  Nick and other Autofac contributors *should* provide whatever they feel like providing.  Perhaps you could contribute a better solution.

Comment: Just remembered: Nicholas actually demonstrates my example in his own comments on that page. He uses a nameless implementation service and even argues the name parameter on RegisterDecorator could be optional in the future. This functionality was clearly *supposed* to be supported.

Comment: Are you talking about the comment where he says "The API might be better if it was also an optional argument"?

Comment: Correct. Someone asks (as I have) 'Does the service to be decorated have to be registered using a named key?', and Nicholas replies 'no – you can pass a null fromKey. The API might be better if it was also an optional argument'. However, I get an error when I attempt this.

Comment: Sure, but saying "the API *might* be better" is hardly the same as saying the functionality is "*supposed* to be supported".

Comment: Clearly. Nonetheless, he states 'you can pass a null fromKey'... try doing it however, and it breaks.

Comment: No - when passing a null `fromKey` you need to pass a valid `toKey`: the requirement that these are different is an intentional part of the API and wouldn't be affected. The observation is only that C# makes it awkward to have "or" parameters of the same type. Lawrence, I know it is unintentional but your tone really comes across as argumentative in this thread. Ben's been working with Autofac a long time and clearly wants to help. To get the information you seek on SO, you need to write a very clear question and invest time in guiding respondents. The process takes effort from both parties.

Comment: +1 for Nick's comment.  I remain disappointed at the down vote and the tone in these comments.  It certainly will not encourage me to answer your questions in the future.  Regardless, I have updated the answer to reflect the additional suggestion from Nick and clarified the usage of fromKey and toKey.  I hope this will help other Autofac users.

Comment: No problem guys - valid points. I appreciate that you are catering for the 'broadly applicable' usage, but the decision to *explicitly* not cater for decorator-less usage still seems bizarre to me; especially when your interfaces support it. I will start to use OnActivating instead.

Comment: And thanks for the help too :) I have up voted as the response now answers my question, albeit not the solution I had hoped for.